# Scala: How to replace all element in a List?

Tags: scala

I have a list contains elements in this class:

```
case class DiningRecord(
                     name: String,
                     cuisine: String,
                     address: String,
                     timeOfVisit: String)
```

Now I need to generate a new list or replace elements in the original list by cuisine String. Is there any way I can do it? I'm new to Scala.

Comment: are you saying you want to change cuisine of you list? To what? And mutate all cuisine by the same new cuisine?

Comment: "Is there any way I can do it?" – Yes, there is. You can do it by writing a program which does what you want. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, traits, types, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a field in a data class, use `.copy` and change the value you want to change.

see REPL example,

```
scala> case class DiningRecord(name: String, cuisine: String, address: String, timeOfVisit: String)

scala> List(DiningRecord(name = "name1",
                         cuisine = "cuisine1",
                         address = "some address",
                         timeOfVisit = "2017"),
            DiningRecord(name = "name2",
                         cuisine = "cuisine2",
                         address = "some address",
                         timeOfVisit = "2018")).map(_.copy(cuisine = "new cuisine"))
res10: List[DiningRecord] = List(DiningRecord(name1,new cuisine,some address,2017), 
                                 DiningRecord(name2,new cuisine,some address,2018))
```

The example above creates a new list of data with cuisine as `new-cuisine`